# Does RSA_PRBG security depend on keeping seed secret?

Tags: rsa, random-number-generator, randomness

The HAC provides a [PRBG using RSA (Chapter 5 p.185)](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap5.pdf):

[image]

It appears the seed must be kept secret if $e$ is a well known value. If $e$ is uniformly distributed between 1 and $\phi$, then the seed does not need to be secret.

The first question is, are the observations of the seed correct?

The second question is, for second (and subsequent) random numbers, can step (1) be skipped. That is, can the RSA parameters be reused?

Comment: Yes, step 1 can be skipped which is why it's labeled _Setup_.  However re-using these parameters forces you to trust the source of them, because otherwise the attacker might know the $d$ corresponding to $e$, invalidating at least the forward secrecy of the PRNG.

Comment: Assuming you choose e=3, which is good for processing efficiency, note that, if the adversary knows n, then he has the same PRBG as you do.